# Neo4J - How to create a new node based on splitting an existing relationship property and automatically creating a link?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, visualization

I have a network of nodes which represent **People** which are connected by relationships (**Emails**).

The Receiver of the Email is **m.slug**

*Based on:  ()-[r]-(m)*

I wish to split the property (in this case "Sender" / m.slug ie Larry@google.com)and create a new node "Google.com" AS Company (i.e so I now have a set of Company nodes created from the existing information).

I want to then link Google (the company) to my Person Node (Larry@Google.com).

--

How would you approach this, without creating multiple duplicate Company nodes? (i.e for Sergey@Google.com & Larry@Google.com should be connected to the same Google.com Company Node).

[Visual Representation of People and relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwpw.png)

[Example syntax of queries and relationship properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxuRa.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can ensure there is a unique `Company` node for each email address domain name, and associate it (via an `AT` relationship) with each `Person` with an email address in that domain. The domain name is lower-cased before storing, to ensure uniqueness, since email addresses frequently come with different casing.

```
MATCH (n:Person)
MERGE (c:Company {name: TOLOWER(SPLIT(n.slug, '@')[1])})
CREATE (n)-[:AT]->(c);
```

*NOTE: The above query should only be executed ONCE, since the `CREATE` clause would create the relationship every time, even if it already exists. You can replace `CREATE` with `MERGE` if you need to run the query multiple times.*

Comment: Thanks Sam - I tried to run the code above and received 
_"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError
Cannot merge node using null property value for name"_
--
I tried to then change the name of the query to CompanyName 
`MATCH (n:Person)
MERGE (c:Company {Companyname: TOLOWER(SPLIT(n.slug, '@')[1])})
CREATE (n)-[:AT]->(c);`
_However I received the same response and now created two relationship properties (Name & Company Name) that can't be used_
--
No new Nodes have been created in the process (i.e no Company Nodes)
Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems that not all your `slug` values have a `@` character. You should sanitize your data to make sure that all `slug` values are valid email addresses before making the above query.